# Java time zone for Ottawa?

Tags: java, timezone

Why the TimeZone returned by the following line showed incorrect time :

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Ottawa")
```

It showed 10:26 PM now [ Atlanta time now is 6:26 , Ottawashould also be 6:26 pm ].

I thought it has two parts : continent/city and it should return the correct time, am I incorrect ?

Comment: That doesn't return a time at all, it returns a `TimeZone`. So I don't understand your question.  Does `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Ottawa"));` not behave like you want?

Comment: what do you mean by "incorrect time"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct timezone is `America/Toronto`.  This is the largest city in the province of Ontario.

Timezone names are typically in the form Continent/City.  For Canada and the United States, the timezones use the largest city in the State or Province.  A few states have multiple timezones in the form of Continent/State/City.  For most other countries there is at least one timezone using the largest city. Countries with multiple timezones usually use the largest city in each timezone.

EDIT: The likely reason for your time difference is that the code defaults to Zulu time if the timezone is not found.

Comment: I thought the same thing - when I use Toronto, I get the same result as Ottawa...

Answer (score 1):

You can't just pick cities at random. `America/Toronto` is the appropriate time zone if Java uses the same [time zone database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) as everyone else.

Comment: While it happens to not be in the list, to be perfectly fair, it's the IS the capital of Canada, which makes it's surprising it's not included.

Comment: @glowcoder, Your argument might make sense it if was Canada's time zone, but Canada has 6. Furthermore, the time zone extends out of Canada.

Comment: Toronto is the capital of Ontario which is the province Ottawa is located in, and a far larger city.  I believe city size is the primary factor.  The timezone for the Province of Quebec is America/Montreal, but its capital city is Quebec.  Same applies to some other provinces.

Comment: @BillThor, Oddly, neither the largest nor the capital was used for New Brunswick.

Comment: @ikegami: Saint John NB is easily confused with Saint Johns Nfld in a different time zone (half an hour ahead).  Moncton is clearly NB, and currently has a slightly larger Metropolitan population.

Comment: @BillThor, Especially when you misspell it. The convention is St John's, NL.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes the convention is St John's, but it is pronounced Saint Johns.  Saint John NB is also seen as St John.  The spelling and location of the two cities is a common confusion in Canada.

Comment: @BillThor, I didn't dispute the confusion. In fact, I agreed with it. I know first hand since I'm from Saint John.